# Junit : Test case for New Method which Returns Object

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I am new to Junit. I am trying to follow TDD. My task is to write a test case for a new method. My method's signature is `public Message getMessage(String id)`

The responsibility `getMessage(String id)` is to take messageId as parameter and query DB and populate Message object from resultSet and return.

Message Bean has four members

- messageID : int
- message : String
- creationDate : Date
- author : String

My confusion is :

- How do I write a test case with Dummy ID as a method argument and then validate returned Object Message for some predefined dummy values?

Comment: What are you trying to test here? Sounds like you need some test data in the database.

Comment: Learn about mocking.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?  Are you using a JDBC Driver, or an Object Relational Manager?  You may need to mock the connection.  A unit test would NOT touch a live database.  Unit tests should run quickly, and should isolate the code under test as much as possible.  Adding a real database (even with test data) introduces so many variables that the test becomes far less useful.

Comment: @BobbyStJacques Don't write a unit test for a DAO: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/writing-tests-for-data-access-code-unit-tests-are-waste/

Comment: I am using JDBC driver to connect DB. I know that I need to mock connection/ but, my confusion is how do I validate/assert output of the method with dummy data. So, I need help in test case.

Comment: @Incredible Well, if you know how to mock, add your test setup to your question so we can help you with the asserts. Also add the method you want to test.

Comment: I don't want to test DB connection. Just want to test this method works. but, this method uses DB connection to get required message based on message Id

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. If you want to test data access layer code within this method, use DBUnit. You need to insert sample data first and then query it using this function. Once test is done, remove the sample data.

   [http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/](https://github.com/jayway/powermock)
2. If you just want to check business logic. Then you can mock all method call within `getMessage` method using powermock or easymock. And test this method only. Check powermock here
   https://github.com/jayway/powermock

Answer (score 1):

When I have some complex object as "expected", I use Spring to build it.

For example:

Entity class:

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // getters, setters, constructors goes here
    // ! IMPORTANT ! equals and toString must be implemented properly.
}
```

Method to test:

```
public class SomeClass {
   public static Person getPerson(long id) {
      // return some real Person object from database
   }
}
```

And to write my "expected" object I use Spring:

```
<bean id="person" class="Person">
   <property name="id" value="1">
   <property name="name" value="John">
   <property name="age" value="42">
</bean>
```

Then in Test method:

```
Person expected = springContext.getBean("person", Person.class);
Person actual = SomeClass.getPerson(1);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

If you don't have implemented `getPerson` yet, you can use Something like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to mock this method and return dumm object, which can be constructed also with Spring.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I need to write this test case without Spring. Can you provide me one implementation without using Spring ?

Comment: Ok, if you cannot use Spring for tests, just create objects explicitly.
Like `Person person = new Person(); person.setId(1);...`

Comment: but I want to Mock DB, Don't want to use real DB for test.